# Logo gets cut off in meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The meta logo is getting cut off:

[image]

It happens for me in both IE9 and Chrome.

Comment: Looks like Firefox, too.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not a big deal. Just pointing out it's rather _expected_.

Comment: it will be fixed in the next build(today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jin fixed it in the most recent build.

Comment: Posted this so that I can have something to accept ;-)